# Relation between position of stars and locations of gemstones?

Tags: star

A theory has been said that the patterns and positions help identify where valuable gemstones are hidden. I am wondering if this has any truth in it.

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about complete and utter drivel, not astronomy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pseudoscience.

Comment: No truth at all. Where did you get this?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, there is no truth in that, at all. No body out of our Solar System could interfere in Earth's techtonics nor in Geology in any way.

Comment: Can you really go so far to say this? I'm just curious for a mathematical proof. Say black whole of a few solar masses where to make a close pass by the solar system or some similar situation. Could this not perturb orbits ultimately leading various surface perturbations? Just postulation. The gemstones part is total nonsense but I just question your second sentence.

Comment: @RyanMcGaha: A mass that large that close is actually rather unreasonable, but let's roll with it anyway. Take the gravitational tidal forces on the Earth due to the Moon (orbital distance $R$) as the standard of comparison. The ones due to the Sun are $(M/m)(R/1\,\mathrm{AU})^3 \sim 1/2$ as large. Say the "size" of the solar system as roughly the heliopause distance $120\,\mathrm{AU}$, so that the tidal forces of this hypothetical mass are at most $3\times 10^{-7}$ of the Moon's.

Comment: Alright I see how you got your answer now. Sorry, I like to see math to prove it.